# Best Domain Host for App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, web-hosting

I'm now paying Dreamhost for domain hosting, and I was pleased with it when I was actually using their shared hosting, but now I'm a paying customer of Google's App Engine service and I haven't moved more than a few dozen megabytes of data to or from the Dreamhost server in over a year.

I'm now investigating the different ways I could be organizing my domains without needing to pay for a full shared hosting service, and wondering if there was any good experiences with basic domain hosting solutions.

Of course, I'd be happy to pay Google extra for this feature to be baked in more fully to the App Engine service, but outside of that I've considered running my own Nginx server, trying to switch to a bare-bones registrar, or even just contacting Dreamhost and seeing if I can negotiate the price if I'm willing to give up all my storage and bandwidth.

Too bad, because I think their tools and support is unmatched by Google, frankly. But when I can pay by the penny for App Engine, it's tough to continue to pay for a service I'm really not using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just transfer your domains to any registrar of your choosing. I'm partial to register4less, but godaddy is a reasonable (and common) choice; both of them provide full DNS hosting on top of registrar services, which is all you'll need if you're hosting your stuff on App Engine.

Comment: What you ideally need is a registrar with full CNAME support for the www.yourdomain.com alias to ghs.google.com and URL forwarding for the naked domain support youdomain.com to www.yourdomain.com. Otherwise you will need some form of hosting where you can set a 301 re-direct on the naked domain to the www. subdomain.